# DUAL-GTX1060-O3G) drivers for linux

Tags: ubuntu-drivers

DUAL-GTX1060-O3G drivers for Linux? I want to install this into my motherboard gigabyte. Step by step using terminal thanks I'm a newly don't use terminal but want to try!

Answer (score 0):

Go to Sotware & Updates -> Additional drivers and install a recommended driver.